# Linux not using all memory

Tags: centos, fedora, linux-kernel

I have a PC with Fedora 23 OS with 4 GB RAM, but usable memory is 2 GB.
When I tried to check memory:

```
# dmesg | grep Memory
[    0.000000] Memory: 1753008K/1816676K available (7670K kernel code, 1264K rwdata, 3336K rodata, 1508K init, 1544K bss, 63668K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
[    4.930051] [drm] Memory usable by graphics device = 2048M
```

Here is the output from free -m:

```
# free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           1731        1065          77         124         588         483
Swap:          1023          44         979
```

How can I use all of my memory?

Comment: Are you sure that the RAM is detected correctly by the BIOS?

Comment: I am sorry? How to check RAM detected by BIOS is correctly or not?

Comment: That depends on the BIOS. Usually at the first stage of the boot process there's something like "Press F12 to enter setup" or whatever written on the screen. So press the button, go into the setup, and then there's usually some kind of information page. Alternatively, many BIOS print the detected RAM at every boot for a short moment, but that might flash by too fast.

Comment: also post the top lines of the bootlog, where the kernel parameters are visible.

Answer (score 1):

This could be ganged-mode RAM operation (see here: http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/278881-30-what-ganged-unganged-mode).

Check in your BIOS that the memory slots are properly detected and not ganged.

`dmidecode` or `dmidecode -t` shows you how Fedora sees the RAM.

Comment: PAE would get you above the 4gb mark. This is likely just faulty RAM being marked bad.

Comment: Oh yes, right. Sorry. I am going to edit my answer. I think, this could be ganged-mode RAM operation.